# What should I use other than .findAndModify?

Tags: meteor

I have the following code:

```
var roomDoc = Rooms.findAndModify({
  query: {name: roomName},
  update: {$setOnInsert: {unixTimestamp: unixTimestampSeconds()}},
  new: true,
  upsert: true
});
```

After getting an error that `.findAndModify is undefined`, I realized, Meteor doesn't implement `.findAndModify`.

Is there a Meteor way  to achieve similar functionality by using different queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the obvious thing just to do the `find()` and `upsert()` separately.

```
Rooms.upsert({name: roomName}, {$setOnInsert: {unixTimestamp: unixTimestampSeconds()}};
var roomDoc = Rooms.findOne({name: roomName});
```

This is probably slightly less efficient because of two db calls but if that bothers you just write your own meteor wrapper for Mongo's `findAndModify()` by using Rooms.rawCollection().

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, kind of strange how it's not there already, I think.

Answer (score 7):

However the answer above explains this specific case, in many other cases it is supposed that `findAndModify` is an atomic operation that could be used for example to generate unique IDs:

http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

It seems that Meteor won't implement a wrapper of `findAndModify` as a corresponding ticket is already closed, however the community proposed several solutions that already work on both server and client sides:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1070

Answer (score 3):

You can do this directly, with slightly different syntax.

```
var roomDoc = Rooms.rawCollection().findAndModify(
  { name: name }, 
  [], 
  { $setOnInsert: {unixTimestamp: unixTimestampSeconds()} }, 
  { new: true, upsert: true }
)
```

More info here:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/automatically-increment-order-numbers/11261/12